# Migrating Django application to alternate database only

Tags: python, django

I have a Django project with multiple applications. I want one of these applications (named `warehouse`) to go to a specific database (also named `warehouse`), but it doesn't seem to work as I expect. When I migrate this app from the command line (`python manage.py migrate warehouse`), I get a success message:

```
>>> python manage.py migrate warehouse
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: warehouse
Running migrations:
  Applying warehouse.0001_initial... OK
```

The migration appears in the `default` database, which is wrong, but no tables get created, which is correct. If I change the command to the following:

```
>>> python manage.py migrate warehouse --database=warehouse
```

the tables show up in my `warehouse` database correctly, as does the migration. How can I change things so that the first command throws an error, or at least indicates that the given application cannot be applied to the default database?

Here's my setup:

**Database Setup in settings.py**

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'projects',
        'USER': 'myuser',
        'PASSWORD': 'mypassword',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '5432',
    },
    'warehouse': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'projects-warehouse',
        'USER': 'otheruser',
        'PASSWORD': 'otherpassword',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '5432',
    },
}

DATABASE_ROUTERS = ['warehouse.dbrouter.WarehouseRouter', 'base.dbrouter.BaseRouter']
```

**dbrouter.py [Warehouse App]**

```
class WarehouseRouter:
    def db_for_read(self, model, **hints):
        if(model._meta.app_label == 'warehouse'):
            return 'warehouse'

        return None

    def db_for_write(self, model, **hints):
        if(model._meta.app_label == 'warehouse'):
            return 'warehouse'

        return None

    def allow_relation(self, obj1, obj2, **hints):
        if(obj1._meta.app_label == 'warehouse' and
           obj2._meta.app_label == 'warehouse'):
            return True

        return None

    def allow_migrate(self, db, app_label, model_name=None, **hints):
        if(app_label == 'warehouse'):
            return db == 'warehouse'

        return None
```

**dbrouter.py [All Other Apps]**

```
class BaseRouter:
    def db_for_read(self, model, **hints):
        return 'default'

    def db_for_write(self, model, **hints):
        return 'default'

    def allow_relation(self, obj1, obj2, **hints):
        if(obj1._state.db == "default" and obj2._state.db == "default"):
            return True

        return None

    def allow_migrate(self, db, app_label, model_name=None, **hints):
        return db == 'default'
```

Comment: This is expected behavior. Read [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/multi-db/#synchronizing-your-databases). You can't set it up to get an error, unless you don't define a `default` database which forces you to always run with the `--database` option.

Comment: Is there no way I can configure the database router to reject the `warehouse` on `default` case? The documentation you linked to seems to hint that that should be possible.

Comment: No just always run migrations for all your dbs. With your router settings, the correct migrations will be made to the correct db.

Answer (score 1):

You use databases for persisting your models, and Django use databases as well to keep track of migrations, and if you do not specify any database name while migrating an app, Django will use the `"default"` database for store the migration metadata.

That's the expected behavior. When you do:

```
>>> python manage.py migrate warehouse
```

Django saves migrations to de default database and tables goes on `warehouse` database just because of `WarehouseRouter`.

and then when you do:

```
>>> python manage.py migrate warehouse --database=warehouse
```

Then Django "knows" it has to put migrations in another place that "default" database.

I've not tested but I think this would work (migration and tables creation, no writing and reading to/from models) even without `WarehouseRouter`.

Comment: I feel like the router is required. I specifically *do not* want the `warehouse` data to appear in my `default` database.